# JCreator IDE: Program will compile but not run, works in command prompt

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, javac, jcreator

Recently purchased a new computer, trying to resume developing Java. One of the IDEs I use, JCreator, has started spitting out errors at me. I uninstalled and reinstalled Java a few times on the new machine to get everything working.

I have a syntactically correct program, compiles just fine, but whenever I try to run the program from within the IDE, it spits out an error message. It reads as follows:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-server   to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

Process completed.
```

I am assuming this is merely instructions for how to hook up the runtime environment.

The kicker is that all runtime settings under:

Configure > Options > JDK Tools > Run Application

are the exact same on my old machine which runs everything just fine.
I know this has to be a JCreator problem because I can compile everything perfectly fine from command line and then run it.

javac and java commands work in command line, just this one thing will not work in JCreator.

Any ideas on the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem that JCreator developer's are aware of, and are trying to find a solution to.
[Discussion on JCreator's forum board about this](http://www.jcreator.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=7905&st=0)

The problem exists when a file is opened through windows explorer.

In order to not experience this problem:
Open JCreator.
Open your file (*do not close the JCreator **Start Page** tab*).

You should have no problems running your file as long as the Start Page tab is open (and in the first position).

Comment: +1 for a working solution. I would just like to add for anyone else who finds this through searching: if you already have the file opened in JCreator by dragging it, you'll have to completely restart JCreator before it will run properly. You can't just close the file and open it within JCreator.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for you to do is to copy all your source code, create a brand new project, past the source code, and then build it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I was tired of it, this is a very huge problem.

The cause is that you have to know that Jcreator works on x86 architecture, so you must install 32-bit Java version, and in the configuration of Jcreator,you must choose the path of 32 bit version of Java

> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66 )

Any time you may get this error, make sure to check the path of Java in config of Jcreator. This solved the problem for me, hope it works.